# How to have a group of buttons, where the effect is accordion-like, showing only one drop-down at a time?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

Trying to create a simple restaurant menu. The idea is to have a bunch of buttons on the top, each labeled (e.g. omelets, pancakes, burritos, etc). When a button is pressed the information for the category would drop down.

However, I only want one category to show at a time. So, if you press omelet, the omelet options drop down. Then you press pancakes, the omelet info goes away and the pancake info drops down.

And I'm stumped on how to make this happen. I tried something similar with an accordion, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Here's what I've got so far (the menu info is incomplete, but you get the picture):

```
<p>
   <div class="container"><div class="row justify-content-center">
    <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#omelet" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="omelet">Omelets — Proven Favorites!</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#favorites" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="favorites">Favorites of Our Regulars</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-1 mr-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eggCombo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="eggCombo">Egg Combinations</button>
  </div></div>
  </p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="omelet">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <div>
                <b>Cheese Omelet</b> — Choice of Jack, Cheddar, Swiss, Cream Cheese or Bleu Cheese
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Turkey, Spinach, Onion, & Cheese Omelet</b><br>
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Mushroom & Cheese Omelet</b>
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Chili Cheese Omelet</b>
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Veggie & Cheese Omelet</b> — Sautéed Mushrooms, Onions, Green Peppes, Zucchini, & Spinach
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Avocado, Cream Cheese & Chive Omelet</b>
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Mexican Cheese Omelet</b> — Chorizo, Mushrooms, Onions, Green Peppers, Zucchini, & Jack Cheese
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>Spinach, Mushroom & Cheese Omelet</b> — Hugh & Jean Special
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="favorites">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <b>André's Suggestions</b> — 1 biscuit & sausage gravy with 2 eggs & 2 strips of bacon; OR 1 biscuit & veggie gravy with extra veggies & fruit<br>
          <b>Whoopie's Breakfast</b> — 2 eggs any style, bacon, potatoes, toast, and large orange juice<br>
          <b>Nova's Favorite</b> — Spinach, eggs, and cheese scrumptiously scrambled and served with fruit, tortillas, small fresh squeezed O.J. and lots of salsa<br>
          <b>Bob's High Carbohydrate Runner's Breakfast</b> — 1 high protein pancake, 2 eggs any style, and potatoes<br>
          <b>Lily's Special</b> — Bowl of rice & cheese, small fruit plate, muffin<br>
          <b>Laura's Regular</b> — 1/2 raisin bread French toast, 2 strips of bacon, 1 egg<br>
          <b>Damian's Breakfast Burrito</b> — 2 eggs scrambled with salsa, avocado, and cheese, rolled in a tortilla, topped with sour cream and served with potatoes<br>
          <b>Dick's Diet Delight</b> — 2 eggs poached on an English muffin, seasonal fruit or small O.J.<br>
          <b>John's Special</b> — Granola with seasonal fruit and muffin; OR oatmeal with seasonal fruit and muffin<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="eggCombo">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <div>1 egg any style</div>
            <div>2 eggs any style</div>
            <div>2 eggs, 2 strips of Bacon</div>
            <div>2 eggs, 4 strips of bacon</div>
            <div>2 eggs, sausage</div>
            <div>2 eggs Ham <i>PJ's Fave</i></div>
            <div>2 eggs, turkey</div>
            <div>2 eggs, hamburger patty</div>
            <div>2 eggs, corned beef hash</div>
            <div>Huevos rancheros</div>
            <div>Rudy's Huevos Rancheros <i>Chorizo, beans, & green chilies</i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want only the last button pressed to display the associated card. Using Bootstrap4, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

[Toggleable Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp) seem to be better suited for your use case - you can style the button in the color `#007bff` or lightpink or whatever... when you click on a tab, only one tab with corresponding information opens below and others remain hidden.

**snippet** below:

```css
.nav-item {
  background: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Omelets — Proven Favorites</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Favorites of Our Regulars</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Egg Combinations</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h4>Omelets</h4>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div>
          <b>Cheese Omelet</b> — Choice of Jack, Cheddar, Swiss, Cream Cheese or Bleu Cheese
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Turkey, Spinach, Onion, & Cheese Omelet</b><br>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Mushroom & Cheese Omelet</b>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Chili Cheese Omelet</b>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Veggie & Cheese Omelet</b> — Sautéed Mushrooms, Onions, Green Peppes, Zucchini, & Spinach
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Avocado, Cream Cheese & Chive Omelet</b>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Mexican Cheese Omelet</b> — Chorizo, Mushrooms, Onions, Green Peppers, Zucchini, & Jack Cheese
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Spinach, Mushroom & Cheese Omelet</b> — Hugh & Jean Special
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h4>Favorites of Our Regulars</h4>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <b>André's Suggestions</b> — 1 biscuit & sausage gravy with 2 eggs & 2 strips of bacon; OR 1 biscuit & veggie gravy with extra veggies & fruit<br>
        <b>Whoopie's Breakfast</b> — 2 eggs any style, bacon, potatoes, toast, and large orange juice<br>
        <b>Nova's Favorite</b> — Spinach, eggs, and cheese scrumptiously scrambled and served with fruit, tortillas, small fresh squeezed O.J. and lots of salsa<br>
        <b>Bob's High Carbohydrate Runner's Breakfast</b> — 1 high protein pancake, 2 eggs any style, and potatoes<br>
        <b>Lily's Special</b> — Bowl of rice & cheese, small fruit plate, muffin<br>
        <b>Laura's Regular</b> — 1/2 raisin bread French toast, 2 strips of bacon, 1 egg<br>
        <b>Damian's Breakfast Burrito</b> — 2 eggs scrambled with salsa, avocado, and cheese, rolled in a tortilla, topped with sour cream and served with potatoes<br>
        <b>Dick's Diet Delight</b> — 2 eggs poached on an English muffin, seasonal fruit or small O.J.<br>
        <b>John's Special</b> — Granola with seasonal fruit and muffin; OR oatmeal with seasonal fruit and muffin<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Egg Combinations</h3>
      <div class="card card-body">
        <div>1 egg any style</div>
        <div>2 eggs any style</div>
        <div>2 eggs, 2 strips of Bacon</div>
        <div>2 eggs, 4 strips of bacon</div>
        <div>2 eggs, sausage</div>
        <div>2 eggs Ham <i>PJ's Fave</i></div>
        <div>2 eggs, turkey</div>
        <div>2 eggs, hamburger patty</div>
        <div>2 eggs, corned beef hash</div>
        <div>Huevos rancheros</div>
        <div>Rudy's Huevos Rancheros <i>Chorizo, beans, & green chilies</i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```